# Why is only the Zune app available on the Swedish Xbox 360 App Marketplace?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-dashboard

I installed the December 6th 2011 Xbox Dashboard update a few days ago.

I wanted to install the YouTube App but when entering the App Marketplace I only get the Zune app listed.

What's wrong? Is it suppose to be like that, with only one app available?

I live in Sweden and I do NOT have a GOLD account.

Comment: I'll note that Xbox Live Gold is required for most of the online components of the Xbox - including all the video services, at least here in the US.  When YouTube is available on the Xbox, it is likely to require Gold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have both a US Gold Account and a European (Dutch, specifically) Silver account on our machine. On the European Silver account, the situation is indeed as you have stated, with the only available apps being the Zune app.

The difference in app availability is because your account is based in Sweden. If you check [Major Nelson's blog](http://majornelson.com/2011/12/04/the-future-of-tv-begins-this-week-on-xbox-360/), you can find the following:

**Dec. 6th:**

- EPIX - United States
- ESPN on Xbox LIVE - United States
- Hulu - Japan
- Hulu Plus - United States
- LOVEFiLM - United Kingdom
- Netflix - Canada and United States
- Premium Play by (MediaSet) - Italy
- Sky Go (SkyDE) - Germany
- Telefónica España (Movistar Imagenio) - Spain
- TODAY (MSNBC) - United States
- Live television on Xbox 360 with Bing Search support

As you can see, none of these changes currently include Sweden. However, some of the planned updates **later in December** *will* include Sweden, such as:

- MUZU.TV
- MLB.TV (MLB Advanced Media)

There are a couple features which only list that they will be available in several countries, not specifying which ones, including:

- Dailymotion - Available in 32 countries globally
- YouTube - Available in 24 countries globally

Neither Major Nelson's blog nor the accompanying [official press release from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/Presspass/press/2011/dec11/12-04Xbox360TV.mspx) specify which countries are included. I assume Sweden is included, but you'll have to keep an eye out for yourself.

Comment: You are probably right. So far this update has been not much use to me, more hassle than anything else.

Comment: [Supposedly](http://kotaku.com/5867755/youtube-and-more-video-services-hit-the-xbox-360-today), YouTube should be live today in whichever countries they are launching it in.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Apps -> App MarketPlace. But Youtube is still in coming soon, even here in Canada.

Comment: That is what I do, but when I do it I only get one app to download/buy. Thats the problem.

Comment: @Jonas it just might not be available yet.

Comment: @AshleyNunn You are probably right.